# Liveview shows no events

Tags: branch.io

After creating a branch link and using it to install the app, then repeatedly tapping on the link again - that causes the app to re-open I am expecting to see events (install, open, referred session) in Dashboard > LiveView but there are no events recorded there at all.

Is there something I am missing that I need to configure to see events in LiveView?

The marketing view also only shows clicks and nothing against Installs or Re-opens?

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Branch.io here: what you are doing **should** work as you describe, so there is probably some sort of configuration issue. Some things you can check:

1. Are you using the same Branch key inside your app as was used to generate the link(s)?
2. Try enabling [debug mode](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/integration-testing/guide/ios/#use-debug-mode-to-simulate-fresh-installs) to make sure the system isn't throwing out your events as fraudulent
3. The Marketing view sometimes has a delay, but the Live View should be at most 10-15 seconds behind. Are you seeing new data in the Clicks tab, but just not the Events tab?

Feel free to [submit a ticket](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) with additional details, so that we can help debug from the back end!

Comment: Thanks - it was my mistake. I had the wrong key in-app.